# What is the one-to-one property and why does it work for logarithms?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

My algebra textbook says that if the base of the logs are the same in a logarithmic equation, then the one-to-one property can be used to set the arguments equal to each other. My textbook doesn’t provide any explanation why this works or what the one-to-one property is. The only thing about one-to-one functions my textbook has mentioned is that each domain value has a unique range value and vice versa, and if a function is one-to-one, it has an inverse. I’m not sure why these facts allows for the arguments of the log to be equal to each other if the bases are the same. My current understanding of math is at a very basic algebra level, possibly at the level of high school mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean something like this: 
$$\log_b(x)=log_b(y)\implies x=y$$
We can say this because $f(x)=\log(x)$ is an *injective* or *one to one* function. 
We say that a function $f$ is injective if 
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)\implies x_1=x_2$$
$\log(x)$ maps $x$ to an exponent that raises some base, $b$, to obtain $x$. 
In other words, if $\log(x)=a$, then $x=b^a$. Suppose that $y\neq x$ but $\log(x)=\log(y)$. Then, $b^a=x\neq y=b^a$, which is a contradiction, so $x=y$ must hold.

Comment: "Then, if y is some other number" When you say $y$ is some other number, are you saying that it's some other value than $x$? Such as $log (x) = log (y) \Longrightarrow log (2) = log (4)$?

Comment: Or would the one-to-one property mean that $log (x) = log (y) \Longrightarrow log (4) = log (4)$?

Comment: I admit that the wording there was poor, let me edit this.

Comment: I want to say that $x\neq y$ cannot be true given that $\log(x)=\log(y)$, hopefully this makes more sense now.

Comment: These are all kind of "mathy" answers and wording.  Think of $log_b(x)$ as a simple function on $x$.  If two variables $x$ and $y$ produce the same outputs when applied to a function $f$, that is, if $f(x) = f(y)$, and $f$ produces one unique output for every input (that pesky "one to one" business, an example being $f(x) = x+1$), then $x=y$.

Comment: Yes, I think I catch the gist of what both of you are saying.

Comment: I can comprehend how the one-to-one property applies when one log function with varying input is equal to another log function with a constant term as its argument, such as $log_5 (x) = log_5 (25)$, or even $log_5 (x+1) = log_5 (25)$. However, when both log functions have varying inputs/arguments, such as $log_5 (2x) = log_5 (x+1)$, I have difficulty understanding how the one-to-one property applies here (setting arguments equal to each other) since both log functions will have differing outputs for each input and vcie versa.

Comment: The particular to my confusion is the fact that $log_5 (2x)$ and $log_5 (x+1)$ will produce differing outputs for each input. For example, when $x = 4$  then $log_5 (2x) = log_5 (8) = 1.292029674$  and  $log_5 (x+1) = log_5 (5) = 1$. So, I don't see how the one-to-one property would then apply when $log_5 (2x) = log_5 (x+1)$   which would allow us to set the arguments equal to each other as we're dealing with two different functions which will produce two different sets of "pairings" of inputs to outputs.

Comment: You say that you understand the case $\log(x)=\log(y)$, but not the case $\log(2x)=\log(x+1)$. Let $2x=y_1$ and $x+1=y_2$ so we have $\log(y_1)=\log(y_2)$. It's the same as the first case.